# Npgsql.Postgresql Exception 42883 function does not exist when called from C# - is there a working example available?

Tags: c#, postgresql

This seems to be a very common issue.  I have gone through a number of the posts on `PostgresException: 42883`.  Most of these are related to a mismatch in the function signature in the PostgreSQL database and the call from C#.

I am really not seeing the issue.  Could someone enlighten me?

My PostgreSQL function is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.getimportkey(
    instid integer,
    fname character varying,
    fhash text)
    RETURNS bigint
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
declare
        impId bigint;
        begin
        
            select id 
            into impId
            from importlog
            where instrumentid = instId and
                  filename = fname and
                  filehash = fhash;
                  
            return impId;
            
        end;
$BODY$;
```

The C# code that generates the `PostgresException: 42883` exception is below.

```
 using (NpgsqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
        {
            NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("getimportkey", connection);
                                                       
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@instid",NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer,instrumentId);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fName",NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, fileInfo.Name);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fHash", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text, fileHash);

            int? impId = (int?)command.ExecuteScalar();
            if (impId != null) imported = true;

        }
```

I noticed that `varchar(255)` and `character varying` must be considered as equivalent types.  I tried the following:

1. Dropped the `getimportkey` function from the database. I refreshed the function list and confirmed that `getimportkey` is gone.
2. Modified the `CREATE` script as follows:

Changed the definition of the `fname` parameter from:

```
 fname character varying,
```

To:

```
  fname varchar(255),
```

3. Executed the modified script.
4. Refreshed the function list.  `getimportkey` is back, but the `fname` parameter type is shown as `character varying`.

I am guessing that `varchar(255)` is considered the same type as `character varying`.

Can anyone direct me to a working example of calling a PostgreSQL function with parameters from C#?

Comment: Looks like you type is char (one character) instead of an array.  See : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-character.html?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is declared with lower-case parameter names, but the c# code is using two capitalized names, so they don't match (`@fName` and `@fHash`)

You should use lowecase names in the calling code too, or ditch the names to rely on positional parameters only.